# Spring Integration Java DSL: file inbound exception propagation

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Given the following file inbound:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(s -> s
                        .file(directory, new LastModifiedFileComparator())
                        .patternFilter(inputFileNamePattern)
                        .preventDuplicates(),
                      e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(filePollerTrigger))
)
```

and the trigger that throws exception in case certain time was overreached, how does one receives exception that was thrown?

Will it appear in *flow exception channel* or in *inbound specific error handler*?

What is the correct way to deal with it in java dsl?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception thrown from the `trigger.nextExecutionTime()` causes the polling task to be stopped, or not rescheduled if that sounds better:

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule() {
    synchronized (this.triggerContextMonitor) {
        this.scheduledExecutionTime = this.trigger.nextExecutionTime(this.triggerContext);
        if (this.scheduledExecutionTime == null) {
            return null;
        }
        long initialDelay = this.scheduledExecutionTime.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.currentFuture = this.executor.schedule(this, initialDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return this;
    }
}
```

As you see by code it is fully equivalent to the `null` from the trigger. We just exit from the rescheduling loop.

Consider to implement the exception handling logic in the custom `Trigger` as a wrapper around that target one. For example `ErrorHandlingTrigger`.